# Equinox with SWT/Jface

Tags: java, swt, osgi, jface, osgi-bundle

How can I run JFace Application Window through Activation Bundle?

I created new thread in BundleActivator start method, but I get error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: SomeBundle [7]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.swt
```

There is my manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: SomeBundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: SomeBundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: mypackage.mybundle.host.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: me
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: mypackage.mybundle.host,
 org.eclipse.swt,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: mypackage.mybundle.host
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.104.1"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You bundle imports the package `org.eclipse.swt`, which means you need to install a bundle into your OSGi Framework that exports that package.

The package `org.eclipse.swt` is exported by a bundle which is also named `org.eclipse.swt` so it is easy enough to find. Because SWT contains native code you also need to include the platform-specific SWT fragment for your platform, e.g. `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64`.